# Queries Azure Table Storage Composite Partition keys

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage

I have a table in Azure Table storage with partition keys like this

__  (where  is some kind of non fixed length string)

and example could be `"96a38291-c654-461f-a344-6d0157c382b9__6960"`

I think I got the correct filters for what I want and would like a clarification for why it work. Given the above pattern, there is many different guids and different postfixes after __.

Doing a query like `(PartitionKey ge '96a38291-c654-461f-a344-6d0157c382b9') and (PartitionKey le '96a38291-c654-461f-a344-6d0157c382b9a')`

I would get all the entities that has guid equals 96a38291-c654-461f-a344-6d0157c382b9, (notice the little a at the end of the second part).

I just tested it with a few guids and postfixes and it seem to return only the rows of the matching guid. Can someone explain why this works and if there are cases where it wont work, outline those. You may assume that the guid is always a valid guid with the same length.

I assume its something with the comparison of the strings is done from the left char first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works because it's a string comparison; you are asking for all the rows that start with 'guid', and are 'less' than 'guida'.  Because 'a' lowercase is greater than '*' in an ASCII table, your 'a' serves as the upper boundary of your search.  So 'guid*' is less than 'guida'.

Answer (score 0):

In using the guid as the greater than value and the guid + 'a' as the lesser than value you are selecting only the partitions that start with the guid followed by an ascii character less than 'a' which '_' is.

Let me know if this explanation doesn't make sense.

Thanks!